# GENEXUS Instalation Erro Android SDK "Android SDK for Genexus Setup error"

Tags: android, sdk, genexus

I have error with Android SDK Installation for Genexus.

I have install all platforms and componentes of Genexus (NodJs, Visual Studio, SQL Server, Apache, Maven, Framework SDK, Java, etc.) also i download file "commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip" on browser and the download was successfully. This file i was rename to "AndroidSDK.zip" and do not resolve problem

This problem is apparear with executable "androidsdk17.exe" and present this error message:

Android SDK for Genexus Setup error

Unable to download file:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip

into
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\ART\AndroidSDK.zip
Please verify your Internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the wizard for some reason cannot access the internet to download the file. Probably due to some security problem, proxies or something like that.

I think the best way to install Android requirements is by downloading "Android Studio" on your local machine, it would install all the requirements for you.

Another way is downloading manually the URL of the error.

Comment: Thanks by your answer, I done download using the URL " https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip" on browsers I.E., Edge, Firefox and Chrome and i could downloaded withou problems.

I get these errors on my house and i havent proxy, I use Virtual machines on VMWare WorkStation 15 and the S.O. it havent  Antivirus  and Firewall. Internet problem I don't think it's the cause.

Comment: Ok, then download Android Studio and get all the requirements you need using de SDK Manager included in there.

Comment: Ok, I will do it, I will use Android Studio. Thanks